# LTspice modelling for the end terminal side

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, voltage-measurement, bus, shunt

So I have this model. I am trying to build a current/voltage converter circuit for a bus carrying current to the other end of the bus, because I need to give this voltage output from the amplifier to a ADC of a micro controller to read the voltage data. I have the circuit below.[image]

So here, the R5 is my shunt resistor across which my I need to identify the voltage. And R6 is the actual end terminal of the wire.

The question here is, I don't know what kind of internal circuitry is on the end terminal, is there a way to put a module or component on the simulation circuit, which will allow me to only read the data appropriate to the real circuit? Every time I change the value of the considered R6, the output changes. So I am trying to understand what is the best approach to simulate the circuit without the other end circuitry?

The max current from the current source is 40mA.

How do I simulate the shunt resistance part without the data of the other end?

Comment: Your signal is a **current**, but you want to measure/amplify a **voltage**, you use a shunt resistor to convert the current into a voltage. Would it not be easier to just say you want to measure the signal **current** as a current shunt + voltage amplifier is basically a current to voltage converter? You need to reconsider the values of the left PULSE source, 24mA into a 1k resistor (R6) gives 24 V, R2 and R4 make about 12 V from that, the opamp is supplied by +/- 12 V so the input common mode voltage is too close to the supply voltage.

Comment: Hi, I think there was a little confusion with the question, have edited it. Also thank you for the input voltage hint. I have give +15/-15V for the opamp input now. BUt the main part is the r6 part, I am not even sure if I should use resistor or any other component for the simulation.

Comment: The signal current needs to go somewhere so indeed R6 is needed. There's no need for it to have such a high value though, 100 ohms is probably a better choice. Only if the signal is at a high frequency so the cable needs to be terminated by a certain impedance to avoid reflections, then you might need a specific value

Comment: Yes indeed there is a high frequency transmission. The bus communication speed is around 350KHz.

Comment: Mwah, that's not that high (I am used to SPI speeds a couple of MHz), 350 kHz has a wavelength of 857 meter, I bet your cables aren't that long. Then there is no need to consider this signal "high frequency" (no need for special cables etc.). My suggested 100 ohms should work fine.

Comment: Are you sure 741 is the opamp of choice? Could I convince you to try another one? Like anyother? You seem to be working with hundreds of kHz.

Comment: Could you suggest any low supply voltage differential opamps to use? Even I am searching for something that uses less supply voltage for the opamp.

Comment: If you do not intend to increase the gain of the opamp circuit then consider the MCP601. It's cheap, has rail-to-rail in- and outputs  and works on low voltages. It has a GBP of 2.8 MHz so up to 3x gain at your 350 kHz is feasible. If you need more gain (and thus a higher GBP) there are plenty to choose from, for example LT1801. Or choose one from: http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/11085